# MAC OS - How to run an application (.app) via Java class?

Tags: javascript, java, macos

The following Java class code is used to run a program in Windows,

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RuntimeExecTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Opening notepad");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("notepad");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing notepad");
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to run an application (*.app) file in MAC OS? In MAC OS, the .app files are actually folders. What is the Java class code to run an application in MAC OS?

Answer (score 0):

Just run **open** on any app and it will open

```
open /Applications/Chess.app
```

Use the method:

```
Runtime.exec(new String[]{"open","/Applications/Chess.app"})
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simply [Desktop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

```
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    File file = new File("/Applications/yourApp.app");
    try {
        desktop.open(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```